# Convert 3d video to double 2d video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, 3d, scale

I want to convert 3d video to 2d video. I saw another topic [How to convert a 3D movie to 2D using ffmpeg](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21084/how-to-convert-a-3d-movie-to-2d-using-ffmpeg) but as far I know 3d video is build from 2 videos so I should be double output video. One for left eye and another for right one. One should be build from even frames and another from odd frames. Can it be done using ffmpeg ?

Comment: This hardly depends on which 3D method you use. As not all work the same.

Comment: I have 3d camera. If I record 3d video and for example I will open this video by Vegas Pro 16 it gives me two video tracks, question is that I can get this two video tracks using ffmpeg

Comment: Welcome! Can you share a sample source file or the text mode output of MediaInfo for one of the source files? What ffmpeg commands have you tried so far? What results have you gotten? How have those results differed from your expectations?

Answer (score -1):

ffmpeg  -i "foo.mkv" -vf stereo3d=sbs2l:ml -c:a copy "bar.mp4"